# What happend during the JavaScript interpretation phase?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how JavaScript *interpret* code before execution but I don't found a detailed explanation for what it may happen during this phase.

> JavaScript has no compilation step. Instead, an interpreter in the
>   browser reads over the JavaScript code, interprets each line, and runs
>   it.
>   source: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs98si/slides/overview.html

- What it may happen during the *interpretation* phase?
- Does those steps depends in the environment where JS is executed (browser or not browser (node.js) )?
- Does all browsers do the same interpretaion of code or browsers engines may *interpret* the same code differently?

Comment: That's actually not very true anymore; most modern JS engines have a JITer.

Comment: Was it ever true? You can't really run code line by line when you have to support hoisting.

Comment: "interpret code before execution" — interpreting is a method of execution, not a step in it.

Comment: "It is now possible to create entire web applications in which both client-side and server-side logic is written in JavaScript" — For values of "now" starting in [1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Server-side_JavaScript).